# Working on Javscript OOP project for MERN: Class and Constuctors

Tags: javascript, class, oop, constructor, mern

I am learning about classes and constructors for MERN, and I am stuck on an algorithm.

Basically, this is what I have to do:
create a Ninja class
add attribute: name
add attribute: health
add attribute speed;  give a default of 3;
add attribute strength;. default of 3
add method sayName(); should log ninja's name
add method showStats(); should console log all stats (name, strength, speed and health)
add method drinkSake();  should increase health by +10

This is my code so far:

```js
class Ninja {
    constructor(name,health){
        this.speed = 3;
        this.strength = 3;
    }
    sayName() {
        this.name = "Lemon";
    }
    showStats(){
        this.name = name;
        this.health = health;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.strength = strength;
        console.log(showStats);
    }
    drinkSake(){
        this.health += 10;
    }
    
}
```

and then my constructor is listed at the bottom outside of the functions (I tried to play it inside and I also received an error

```js
const ninja = new Ninja ("lemon", 100){
    Ninja.sayName();
    console.log(ninja.name);
}
```

I am having a problem figuring out where the new instances goes. If you could keep the advice as basic as possible I would much appreciate it.

Comment: Does this helps ? [Classes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_classes.asp)

Comment: a little, i am just confused on my error I got. I put the new instance as the end of the code, but I keep receiving an error that says  'unexpected identifier"

Comment: this is wrong { Ninja.sayName();console.log(ninja.name);} when you define a variable that is defined by a class you do const ninja=new Ninja("lemon",100);

Comment: So i do not new Ninja.sayName() ??? 

I have this now that seemed to work:
const lemon = new Ninja("Lemon");
lemon.sayName();
lemon.showStats();
lemon.drinkSake();

Comment: Nop, you dont need to declare it again, everytime you do a New statment is that you are initializing again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a the way you should implement the ninja class.

```
    // classes get defined at the top of the file since they aren't hoisted.
    class Ninja {
        // This is where you define your constructor method.
        constructor(name,health,speed,strengh){
            this.name = name;
            this.health = health;
            this.speed = speed;
            this.strength = strength;
        }
        sayName() {
            console.log(`Hello my name is ${this.name}`);
        }

        showStats(){
            console.log(`Name: ${this.name}\nSpeed: ${this.speed}\nStrength: 
              ${this.strength}\nHealth: ${this.health}`);
        }
        drinkSake(){
            this.health += 10;
        }
    }
    // Make instances of the class down yonder below the class
    // This is calling the constructor method.
    const benny = new Ninja("Benny Bob", 100,3,3);
    // You can also call the methods on the class
    benny.showStats();
    // Should output 
    // Name: Benny Bob
    // Speed: 3
    // Strength: 3
    // Health: 100
```